# Folder or collection of folders

Tags: rest, architecture

Lets imagine that we have a REST service, to model a Folder structure..... how would I request:

1) a specific folder

2) a list of folders below another folder

As I can see it, I can either create two different endpoints:

```
http://../folder?id=folderid (Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.folder+json)
```

returning one folder

```
http://../folders?parentid=folderid (Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.folder+json)
```

returning a collection of folders

Or select on the accepttype:

```
http://../folders?id=folderid (Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.folder+json)
```

returning one folder.

```
http://../folders?parentid=folderid (Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.folders+json)
```

returning a collection of folders.

Or always just return a collection

What is the preferred method??

Comment: Have a look at [RESTful API Design](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design) for general advices on how to design an API.

Answer (score 0):

A list of top level folders

```
GET http://../folders/
```

The contents of a folder

```
GET http://../folders/folder-a/

GET http://../folders/folder-a/folder-b/
```

Where the content is a folder, it too points at the above URL, if the content is a file, it would point to:

```
GET http://../files/folder-a/file-a/
```

If you wanted to add a file, you would use...

```
PUT http://../files/folder-a/file-b/
```

And expect to find the file at that address on a subsequent GET. Alternatively you would:

```
POST http://../files/folder-a/
```

And it would return the URL of the file you posted, if you were using a POST model rather than a PUT model.

To remove a file, you would use...

```
DELETE http://../files/folder-a/file-b/
```

Let me know if you want anything explained in more detail.

Comment: Think all your GET examples would return a list of folders, but what if you pinpoint exactly one folder, but is id or name... should the endpoint then still return a collection or a single folder?

Comment: I would expect the GET to get a list of files and folders for the specified folder. So if I ask for "exactly folder a", I would get a list of the contents of folder a. So it will always be a collection - plus meta-data for folder a.